# Getting status callback on twilio voice calls and call in-progress duration

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

Im creating an andoid app with twilio calling capability. I have a python backend to handle incoming and outgoing requests. I've created a Twiml app to handle outgoing calls, including the call status.

[image]

Also I've configured the phone numbers to handle incoming calls including call status as below:
[image]

So the way it works is:

outgoing:
Android app call -> twilio -> python backend -> twilio -> callee

inbound:
caller -> twilio -> python backend -> twilio -> android app

On android, I'm using the following method to initiate the voice call:

```
params.put("to", dialledNumber);
ConnectOptions connectOptions = new ConnectOptions.Builder(callingLCNToken).params(params).build();
activeCall = Voice.connect(VoiceActivity.this, connectOptions, callListener);
```

On the python side, I have the following sample code to handle outgoing calls:

```
resp = VoiceResponse()
_to = request.values.get("to")
_from = request.values['From'].split(":")[1]
resp.dial(callerId=_from).number(_to)
return str(resp)
```

But I can't still capture the statuses: busy, no-answer, cancelled, failed as mentioned in this doc: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132547-What-are-the-Possible-Call-Statuses-and-What-do-They-Mean-

Also I want to get the during of call in-progress. But with the current status callback, it seems i'm getting the total time from call initialisation and completion.

I tried using StatusCallbackEvent and the callback URL there, but it didn't work either.

**What should I do to get the correct call statuses and the call in-progress duration?**

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the status callback URL you set up in the number admin is for inbound calls. You should [set status callback URLs for outbound calls on the `<Number>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback) like this:

```py
resp = VoiceResponse()
_to = request.values.get("to")
_from = request.values['From'].split(":")[1]
dial = resp.dial(callerId=_from)
dial.number(
  _to,
  status_callback_event='initiated ringing answered completed',
  status_callback='https://example.com/callStatus'
)
return str(resp)
```